# problem compiling existing react native project

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, expo, native

I am a programmer for a company, and I have made some Android applications in Android Studio, but I have no experience with "react native", I specialize in web programming and databases. There is a developer who created the app for our company in "react native", with which he publishes the application for both Android and iOS.
This person can no longer continue with us, so he gave me the entire project for me to continue. I've been trying to compile it for hours, I installed node js, I imported the entire project in vs code, I tried to run it with the android studio emulator, also with expo, but I can't.
Then I tried to import the "android" folder into androd studio, but it throws thousands of complication errors.
What I need is to recompile the android application with API 33, since otherwise they do not allow us to publish in the play store. Could you guide me a little to see how to continue? I leave you an image of the folder structure.

[image]